# Filtering data using IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```html
students(studentID PK, A, B,sec..) FeesStructure(feeStruct PK, feeA, feeB, ..) FeesCollected(FeesID PK,studentID FK,feeStruct FK, A,B,..)
```

If students.sec = 'A' return FeesStructure.feeA, FeesCollected.A .., etc
Have to create a view that will return data based on an if. FeesStructure table has feeA, feeB
which only apply based on a student's sec. I need to return feeA or feeB based on students.sec

Answer (score 1):

You may use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html):

```
select students.studentID,
  case students.sec
    when 'A' then FeesStructure.feeA
    else FeesStructure.feeB
  end as feesStructure,
  case students.sec
    when 'A' then FeesCollected.A
    else FeesCollected.B
  end as feesCollected
from students, FeesStructure, FeesCollected
where students.studentID=FeesStructure.studentID
  and students.studentID=FeesCollected.studentID
```